# My node.js simple web server doesn't access parent folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems

yesterday i've played a little with Node.js and my first idea is making a simple web server that load an html page with some js files in this way:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log('request starting for: ' + request.url);
    var filePath = path.join('.', request.url);
    if (filePath === './') {
        filePath = './aPage.html';
    }

    path.exists(filePath, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            var extname = path.extname(filePath);
            var contentType = 'text/html';
            switch (extname) {
            case '.js':
                contentType = 'text/javascript';
                break;
            case '.css':
                contentType = 'text/css';
                break;
            }

            fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, content) {
                if (error) {
                    response.writeHead(500);
                    response.end();
                }
                else {
                    response.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type': contentType
                    });
                    response.end(content, 'utf-8');
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            console.log('Something goes wrong ;(');
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.end();
        }
    });
    console.log('Server running!');
}).listen('8080', '0.0.0.0');
```

and everything works.

I decided to put this js script in a subdirectory, modify the lines in:

```
...

var filePath = path.join('..', request.url);
    if (filePath === '../') {
        filePath = '../aPage.html';
    }
...
```

but path.exists() fails to check the existence of html page and others files.

Could you please tell me what's my fault (I thought that was only that trivial change)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to directly run the `js` script from the parent folder instead of from the subdirectory.

for example: if you are in directory `foo` and your `server.js` is in subdir `bar`,
then if you run `node bar/server.js`, then `..` will point to the parent of foo, instead of parent of bar, that's why the file is not found.

```
foo
  +---bar
  |     +----- server.js
  +---- aPage.html
```

You may try to `cd` into `bar` and run `node server.js`.

or change the `../aPage.html` in the script to be `__dirname/../aPage.html`.

PS: you can use `path.resolve` to get the absolute path.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't realize that because i'm inside my c9.io project and i run node from ide!